# Scrapy - Image download does not work in second crawling

Tags: python, pyqt4, scrapy

I wrote a spider to download data from a website and follow a link to get detailed data. 
The spider also downloads images using the default scrapy image pipeline. Everything works fine so far.

But when I start the spider for a second time [with another search term], the image download does not work anymore. The crawling works like supposed to. I do not get any errors.

This is the spider:

```
class DiscoSpider(BaseSpider):

    def __init__(self, query):
        super( BaseSpider, self ).__init__()
        self.name = "discogs"
        self.allowed_domains = ["discogs.com"]
        self.start_urls = [
            "http://www.discogs.com/search?q=%s&type=release" % query
        ]

    # parse all releases for the current search
    def parse(self, response):
        logging.debug('scrapy.parse')
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        li = hxs.select("//div[@id='page_content']/ol/li")

        items = []
        for l in li:
            item = DiscogsItem()

            ...

            # get the link for the callback for the tracklist
            link = l.select("a/@href").extract()[0]
            item['link'] = '' if link == None else link

            # get the img location
            img = l.select("a/img/@src").extract() 
            item['image_urls'] = [None] if img == None else img 

            # get the url for the tracklist callback
            url = urlparse.urljoin('%s%s' % ('http://www.', self.allowed_domains[0]), link)

            # request and callback to get tracklist for release
            item = Request(url, meta={'item':item}, callback=self.parse_tracklist)

            items.append(item)
            yield item        

    # callback to get the tracklist for each release
    def parse_tracklist(self, response):
        item = response.request.meta['item']

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        rows = hxs.select("//div[@class='section_content']/table[@class='playlist mini_playlist']/tr")
        tracklist = []

        for row in rows:
            track = {}

            title = row.select("td[@class='track']/span[@class='track_title']/text()").extract()
            track['title'] = '' if title in [None, '', []] else self.clean_track(title[0])

            ...

            tracklist.append(track)

        item['tracklist'] = tracklist    
        yield item
```

This is the Item:

```
class DiscogsItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    link = Field()
    artist = Field()
    release = Field()
    label = Field()
    year = Field()
    tracklist = Field()
    image_urls = Field()
    images = Field()
    thumb = Field()
```

In my scrapy-settings:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline']
IMAGES_STORE = '/home/f/work/py/discogs/tmp'
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 100
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 20
IMAGES_EXPIRES = 0
```

I run the spider from PyQt-UI in a seperate process and I am new to Scrapy / PyQT / StackOverflow (Sorry for bad formatting).

I am on a Xubuntu 12.04 box with Python 2.7, PyQt4 and Scrapy 0.12.0.2546.

Does anyone know why the second image download does not work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the first of two seemingly independent runs works and the second doesn't, then there's probably some state that is affecting the second run. Initial thought is it could be the discogs server, rate limiting your crawling in some way. Can you post your debug output from the second scrape run (and the summary of the first)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question now, although I dont't really know what the issue was.
What I have done is changing the constructor for the spider like this:

```
class DiscogsSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "discogs"
    allowed_domains = ["discogs.com"]

    def __init__(self, query):
        super( DiscogsSpider, self ).__init__()
        self.start_urls = [
            "http://www.discogs.com/search?q=%s&type=release" % query
        ]
```

I also extend CrawlSpider instead of BasSpider now. Image download is now working like expected.

Thanks.